# Oracle 10g tables

Tags: oracle10g

I have several imported tables from a .dmp file into Oracle10g.

What I need is to obtain the CREATE TABLE statements, along with the constraints, triggers and relationships between all those tables for building a script, instead of continue using the .dmp file.

Is there any way to do it from Oracle's UI or any SQL*Plus command?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of. But you can edit the .dmp file and create a script. I've done it many times.